# "Declare" statement as yet an other way to circumvent the .dll hell?

Tags: vb6, dll

To my astonishment I found VB6 code that uses `Declare` statements to define functions in a .dll that lives in the Program Folder without it being registered on Windows. This seems like a supersimple way to avoid the .dll hell without having to resort to using Side by side manifests. Can I read some more about this somewhere? Are there snags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Declare` statement is used to do "just in time" binding to non-ActiveX DLLs.  Until your program "touches" a Declared entrypoint no attempt is made to load the library.

It basically has nothing at all to do with the topic of DLL Hell.

Muddled thinking can even lead people to plop ActiveX DLLs "next to" the EXE which actually can *result in* DLL Hell because people who tend to do this also use poor techniques for installing and uninstalling applications.

1. Poorly designed application A deployment plops a commonly shared DLL or OCX next to the EXE.
2. Poorly designed application is run, the VB6 runtime can't find the classes in the registry, does a DLL Search using Windows heuristics, immediately locates the DLL next to the EXE and calls its self-registration entrypoint.
3. Innocent, properly designed applications B, C, D are later installed that use the same DLL/OCX and their installers find the library already registered.
4. Poorly designed application A is uninstalled, typically by simply deleteing its folder in Program Files.
5. Applications B, C, and D (and any future applications using the library) are now broken - due to orphaned component registration pointing to a non-existant library.

Moral of the story:

Never, never, never put DLLs "next to" your VB6 application on installation.  If you have private DLLs that are not shared with other applications *even then* put them into a `libs`, etc. folder under the application folder.  Possible exception might be non-COM DLLs, such as those you expect to use `Declare` with.

There is also a great deal of misunderstanding about manifests, of which there are multiple kinds.  The ones you are probably thinking of are application and assembly manifests.

These can be used for selecting among different versions of a library installed Side by Side, or they can be used to isolate applications and assemblies which is the part that has bearing on DLL Hell.

Of course application manifests can be used to specify quite a few other things about how Windows should run the application.

Comment: That was partly enlightening. So, the .dll *is* registered, only just at the first use? I am a little confused about what you mean with non-Com .dll's. How can I know that a .dll is non-Com? Putting homegrown ActiveX-dll's in a subfolder of the application seems little better that plopping it in the application folder itself:you will still throw it away at uninstalltime.

Comment: @Dabbleml, not all DLLs are registered; only ones containing COM objects need to be registered. There are many, many DLLs that are not related to COM (for instance, a lot of the Windows API DLLs themselves). There's no simple way to tell them apart; you can check and see if the DLL contains a type library, perhaps. Putting your DLLs in a LIB subfolder instead of your app's folder keeps them from being loaded unintentionally; see the link I gave you for LoadLibrary in my answer above for why (hint: it's the default search locations the function uses).

Answer (score 2):

Windows searches in a well-documented sequence of folders for [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) (which VB6 uses behind the scenes to resolve Declare declarations). Since the first location on the list of search folders is the app's own folder, your discovery makes perfect sense.

It doesn't resolve the "DLL hell" issue for the most part, though. It can't work for system DLLs, for instance, because Windows preloads most of them. Also, if a DLL is already loaded into memory, Windows may use that copy of the DLL (not sharing data, but code can be reused).

That's part of the reason that manifests were created; they allow an application to strictly define required versions of system DLLs in order to provide certain functionality. VB6's technique is old fashioned (just like VB6).